# How to recover from a git push -force?

Tags: git, github

Here is what happened:

I have two remote git branches: `master` and `feature1`. For some reason I have to use `git push --force` for the `feature1` branch, but I didn't know when I use `git push --force` it will also push the `master` branch. Then, a disaster happened, as I pushed my local `master` branch to the remote repository.

Luckily, my local branch is not too far away from the remote. Basically, my remote `master` has two pull requests merged ahead of my local `master`.

So my problem is: can I reopen the pull request and remerge? I noticed that there is commit version for merge request, so I am worried if I simply make new pull request it will mess up something? Ideally I just want to redo the merging of the two requests.

Is there some other way to recover from this disaster? I learned the `--force` is a really, really bad choice. :(

Update, example of what happened:

I have following branches:

```
master
feature1
origin/master
origin/feature1
```

I integrate two pull requests by using the GitHub's `Auto merge pull requests`. Then, I didn't fetch the `master` branch on my local machine. Thus, I think my `origin/master` is two versions behind the remote master.

Then I accidentally used `git -f push`, which overwrote the remote branch and now I lost the commits from the pull requests on remote repository.

How can I recover from it without messing up other contributors' history?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I recover from an erronous git push -f origin master?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3973994/how-can-i-recover-from-an-erronous-git-push-f-origin-master)

Comment: You will soon (git1.8.5,  Q4 2013) be able to [do a `git push -force` more carefully](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18505634/6309).

Answer (score 100, accepted):

When working with github, refer to [GHugo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43271529/1600898) which gives a foolproof procedure with github. If you're on an in-house (or other non-github) installation, read on.

You can always restore the previously observed state of `master`, by resetting to the old commit and issuing another `push -f`. The steps involved typically look like this:

```
# work on local master
git checkout master

# reset to the previous state of origin/master, as recorded by reflog
git reset --hard origin/master@{1}

# at this point verify that this is indeed the desired commit.
# (if necessary, use git reflog to find the right one, and
# git reset --hard to that one)

# finally, push the master branch (and only the master branch) to the server
git push -f origin master
```

Note, however, that this restores remote `master` to the state most recently retrieved by `git fetch` or equivalent. Any commits pushed by others after the last time you fetched will be lost. However, those commits will still be available in *their* reflogs, so they can restore them using steps like the above.

Comment: the problem is that i did this git push -f, so I overwrite the origin's master branch. And I did this before I fetch my origin/master, so if I do this reset, won't it just reset it to my local origin/master?

Comment: basically i did this git push -f before I use git fetch origin/master

Comment: The command will restore origin/master to its state before the push.

Comment: After running the commands above, you will be at the state you were at before merging the push-requests. Redo the merge at github, and you should be set.

Comment: yep, so how can i redo the merge?

Comment: If github's UI doesn't allow you to redo the merge, you can always do it yourself - find the SHA1 of the commit, issue `git merge COMMIT`, and push the merge. After all, one of the chief advantages of DVCS like git is that one doesn't depend on a centralized service like github.

Comment: `git reset --hard origin/master@{1}` is not working for me: `fatal: Log for 'origin/master' only has 1 entries.`

Comment: This is good but I do not understand how it solves OP’s problem in particular. “retrieved by `git fetch` or equivalent”—but OP won’t have the remote `master` that they are looking for since they didn’t fetch before force-pushing.

Comment: @Guildenstern The truth is that we don't know how often the OP fetched or when the last `git push` to master occurred by someone else. This answer provides the best possible recovery given pure `git`, and documents the limitations. In case of github the answer by GHubo is the best approach.

Comment: We don’t know what other people did, true, but OP did not fetch after integrating the two PRs: “Then, I didn't fetch the `master` branch on my local machine.”.

Comment: @Guildenstern I interpreted that as the OP failing to incorporate the newer versions of remote `master` into their `master`, not that they never ran `git fetch` to refresh the local view of `origin/master`. The OP (likely) did "observe" the `origin/master` that they force-pushed over, which is why the recipe from the answer helped.

Answer (score 55):

Note that, with **Github**, you can use the API to recover a forced push even if you do not have the repository cloned locally (i.e., when you do not have a reflog), or the commit sha.

First, you must get the previous commit sha, the one before the forced push:

```
curl -u <username>:<token> https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/events
```

Then you can create a branch from this sha:

```
curl -u <github-username>:<token> -X POST -d '{"ref":"refs/heads/<new-branch-name>", "sha":"<sha-from-step-1>"}' https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/git/refs
```

Finally, you can clone the repository locally, and force push again to master:

```
git clone repo@github
git checkout master
git reset --hard origin/<new-branch-name>
git push -f origin master
```

Note that with two-factor authentication, you need to provide a token (see [here](https://developer.github.com/v3/auth/) for more information).

Credit: [Sankara Rameswaran](https://medium.com/git-tips/githubs-reflog-a9ff21ff765f)

Comment: You have saved me. I might have to use regex to get the text out of this json file i have now, unless you have another idea but i got my data back even if it's not in a usable format yet

Comment: You deserve a lot more than 1 upvote!!! What a hero, 1.5 days of work not lost forever!

Comment: Thank you so much. You are a saviour. Just to add one more thing: it seems like the command didn't work for me at first. I had to create a github rest api personal access token to use in the command (curl -u name:token). Other than that, all is well

Comment: One thing to add to this otherwise lifesaving answer, github now requires a token when accessing the api using `curl -u <username>:<token>`. See https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token

Comment: This was a huge help when a less experienced colleague force pushed and erased 2 years of git history.  Now I'm learning about how to protect branches...

Comment: Saved me!!! I have had a long list when requesting `https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/events` so I used https://docs.github.com/en/rest/activity/events#list-events-for-the-authenticated-user endpoint to find the SHA.