# There isn't anything to compare. Nothing to compare, branches are entirely different commit histories

Tags: git, github, git-diff

I have a CMS theme installed on my machine. I'm tracking changes to it via git
and decided to back it up on GitHub so I could share those changes.

The theme as provided is also available on GitHub. On my machine I have added
this as a remote upstream. Now I can easily see the changes between my master
and the remote upstream by using the following command:

```
git diff --color master upstream/number
```

If I could add the remote upstream on GitHub I could easily share these changes.
Is it possible to set this relationship on GitHub?

I have tried the following:

```
git push -u origin upstreambranch
```

which adds an `upstreambranch` to the master on GitHub. However trying to
compare both branches doesn't work, the result I get on GitHub is that: "There
isn't anything to compare"

Is there an alternative way to compare these?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. You already pushed your repo up to GitHub? Is it public? If it's public, other people already have access to the code, they can just clone or fork the uploaded repo. "`git push -u origin upstreambranch`...adds an upstreambranch to the master on GitHub". You don't add branches to "the master on GitHub". Please clarify what you mean.

Comment: "However trying to compare both branches doesn't work, the result I get on GitHub is that: 'There isn't anything to compare'". Please explain what you're doing to compare branches on GitHub, and include screenshots if possible.

Comment: I am using a cms called Omeka and a particular theme called Seasons. I have modified this theme and uploaded it here: 
https://github.com/padraic7a/seasons

I would like a visual way (diff) to show people how it is different from the 'original'.

I attempted to do so by downloading and then pushing to github this version:
https://github.com/padraic7a/seasons/tree/upstreambranch

In the post above I explained how I did that, but that it didn't work. Does that make more sense?

Comment: Thanks, that's starting to make a little more sense. Is [this the upstream repo](https://github.com/omeka/theme-seasons) that you're referring to? When you say you downloaded the source, did you download it from GitHub or somewhere else, like [this site](http://omeka.org/add-ons/themes/seasons/). If you downloaded it from anywhere other than GitHub, then actually doing a fork from GitHub instead would have been better for what you're trying to do, unless this is a customization that you're doing for a specific client that isn't meant to be shared publicly?

Comment: I figured out what your immediate problem is, but looking at the bigger picture, you might want to reconsider how you're doing everything, as I've already mentioned in my previous comment...but that depends on what you're ultimately trying to do. Writing an answer for your immediate problem...

Comment: I get you, it's certainly a case where I'm beginning from a bad starting point.

Comment: I got into this situation with a git subtree. I used `git subtree split` to extract changes made in a subtree, pushed the branch to the remote repository from which the subtree originally came, and now I can't merge the changes into any existing branch in that repository. Not sure how to proceed.

Comment: This post on
[Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23344320/there-isnt-anything-to-compare-nothing-to-compare-branches-are-entirely-diffe)
have the answer. Hope that help.

Comment: In my case, all I needed to do was click the "Swap Revisions" button. Could be worth giving that a shot.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

## The Short Answer

It looks like GitHub won't let you compare the branches because ***they don't
actually share any of the same history at all,*** even though they may share
much of the same files and code.

Here is a screenshot of the temporary fork I made of your repo, where I tried to
compare `master` with the `upstreambranch`, like you described. Notice the error
message:

[image: Error message screenshot]

It says:

> There isn't anything to compare.
>
> `master` and `upstreambranch` are entirely different commit histories.

## The Long Answer

You probably downloaded the original source and added it to a completely new
repo instead of cloning the original repo, right? Doing that will make it so
that the history of your repo will be ***completely different*** from the
history of the original repo, since your new repo won't have any of the same
commits with the same sha IDs.

You can see that by doing a reverse log of your `master` branch and the
`upstreambranch`:

```
# Your first commit, see commit sha
git log --reverse master
commit c548d7b1b16b0350d7fbdb3ff1cfedcb38051397 # <== HERE
Author: Padraic Stack <padraic.stack@nuim.ie>
Date:   Wed Apr 2 15:11:28 2014 +0100

    First commit of everything

# First commit sha of the original repo
git log --reverse upstreambranch
commit 105a12817234033c45b4dc7522ff3103f473a862 # <== THERE
Author: Jeremy Boggs <jeremy@clioweb.org>
Date:   Mon Feb 22 16:00:53 2010 +0000

    Creates repo directories for the Seasons theme.
```

## Solutions

If you redo your commits on top of the original history, you should then be able
to compare the branches. There are several different ways that you can redo your
commits, including

```
git rebase --onto
```

and

```
git cherry-pick
```

You also can redo each commit manually, if you have to.

Comment: Thanks for your time on this, I appreciate the effort you put in. Your answer lets me know that what I tried to do isn't possible so I am accepting it.


Just to be clear though, I did mention the error above when I said 
**However trying to compare both branches doesn't work, the result I get on GitHub is that: "There isn't anything to compare"**

Comment: @Jack your welcome. Yes, you did mention that, but you left out the rest of the error message that says "master and upstream ***are entirely different histories.***" That was the key to the issue.

Comment: @Jack do you know what you need to do to compare branches now? If you redo all of your commits on top of the original history, you can then compare the branches. There are several different ways that you can redo the commits, including `git rebase --onto` and `git cherry-pick`.

Comment: git rebase -i origin/master 
this worked for me. After doing this I was able to compare both the branches

Comment: @sujay This is right. After doing that I can compare

Comment: "The Short Answer" .... "The Long Answer" should be the default SO answer format. Perfect

Comment: Any idea how to get rid of the message in green "Compare & Pull Request" leading to a page with "There isn't anything to compare"?

Comment: @user456814 your detailed explanation was really helpful.

Answer (score 264):

If the problem is "main and master are entirely different commit histories.", the following will work

```
git checkout master   
git branch main master -f    
git checkout main  
git push origin main -f
```

Comment: this fixed mine, i didn't know want happened but I wasn't able to make a pull request on github. Until this code.

Comment: Same here. Worked for me. Just to clarify for any other n00bs (like me). Replace _"origin"_ with the name of your repo.

Comment: !!Yes it works thanks a lot. Whoever use this please don't forget to backup your changes or you will miss them!!!!

Comment: I am getting this error error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git

Comment: For everyone who is applying this solution: it will forcefully push changes without making them align. As a result, you will lose all previous commits on the project. So be conscious.

Comment: It would be great if you could add bit explanation to it, rest this worked like charm.
Thanks

Comment: this just deleted my files in the main branch and push everything from master to main, lesson is  take a backup.

Comment: @ozkanpakdil This deleted my files is there a way to get them back?

Comment: they say https://stackoverflow.com/a/12569664/175554 in my case I just copied files back in and moved on :)

Comment: This will remove whatever is inside the main branch and replace everything with the master branch. Just be careful while using this.

Comment: This solution deletes files in main branch

Answer (score 106):

I had a similar situation, where my **master** branch and the **develop** branch I was trying to merge had different commit histories. None of the above solutions worked for me. What did the trick was:

Starting from master:

```
git branch new_branch
git checkout new_branch
git merge develop --allow-unrelated-histories
```

Now in the new_branch, there are all the things from develop and I can easily merge into master, or create a pull request, as they now share the same commit hisotry.

Comment: The first 2 commands can just be collapsed into `git checkout -b new_branch`. This creates `new_branch` off the `master` branch and switches into it.

Comment: `--allow-unrelated-histories` was the key here. Solved the conflict I was having. Thxx

Answer (score 69):

I solve my issue using these commands

```
git checkout [BRANCH]   
git branch master [BRANCH] -f   
git checkout master   
git push origin master -f
```

Comment: this will make changes of [BRANCH] available in master and you wont be able to create pull request

Comment: @Susie short for force!

Comment: For the new "main" branch as default, you can do this way:

`git checkout master  
git branch main master -f   
git checkout main

git push origin main -f
`

Comment: I have made your suggested solution and now my old branch is gone, and I cant get to any of the past commits. Thanks!

Comment: @kunal I followed your suggestion but I probably flipped the branches so I ended up missing all the work. How can I revert this?

I had a local project that was using master as the branch, when I created the repo in github I tried to merge main into master but I got the error explained in the histories were totally different. I followed your answer but ended putting main on master where I had all my work

Comment: I would almost never suggest using force push. That will "overwrite" the branch state on github. Use the rebase, merge or cherry-pick solutions. Force pushing basically discards the state on the server. This may work if you are the only one using the repository, but it is still a dangerous practice. Use force push only if you absolutely know what you are doing.

Comment: Thank you for this much-needed tip.  The result of this instruction was that all of the files that had been placed on the master were moved into the main branch.

Comment: to be extra careful, I suggest that everyone creates 2 new branches to experiment with. However, I tried this and it didn't work for me. but thanks for helping others. still digging

Comment: Work like a charm man

Answer (score 44):

You can force update your `master` branch as follows:

```
git checkout upstreambranch  
git branch master upstreambranch -f    
git checkout master  
git push origin master -f
```

For the ones who have problem to merge into `main` branch (Which is the new default one in Github) you can use the following:

```
git checkout master  
git branch main master -f    
git checkout main  
git push origin main -f
```

The following command will force both branches to have the same history:

```
git branch [Branch1] [Branch2] -f
```

Comment: A line by line breakdown would be useful for beginners. Some of those commands are potentially dangerous.

Comment: I am not a super cool person with git, an explanation will help @blue

Comment: @TaslimOseni Glad to help

Answer (score 23):

**From the experiment branch**

```
git rebase master
git push -f origin <experiment-branch>
```

This creates a common commit history to be able to compare both branches.

Answer (score 11):

if you are here in 2023 do this

```
 git checkout [BRANCH]   
 git branch main [BRANCH] -f   
 git checkout main
 git push origin main -f
```

Answer (score 8):

This looks like undesirable behavior on github's part, but it's fairly easy to fix.  What you want to do is to rebase your branch on a reasonable (*any* reasonable) commit in the existing history.  What you can do is to fetch the github repo and find which tree in its history is most similar to the one you started with.  Start this way:

```
git remote add github u://r/l
git fetch github

myroot=`git rev-list master --max-parents=0`
root_tree=`git rev-parse $myroot^{tree}`

github_base=`git log --pretty=%H\ %T github/master | sed -n "s/$root_tree//p"`
```

---

With any luck, that will find you a commit in the github history that has the exact tree you started with.  Assuming it does,

```
git rebase --onto $github_base $myroot master
```

and you're done.

---

If that doesn't find a matching tree, you get to find a nearest approximation.  Here's one way to get a rough estimate of the differences:

```
git log --pretty='echo %H $(git diff-tree -p -b -U0 '$myroot:' %T|wc -l)' github/master \
| sh
```

which will count the lines in a minimized diff between the tree of each commit in the `github/master` history and your root tree.  It seems reasonable to hope for a nice small difference, you could eyeball the actual diffs on it before calling that the `github_base` commit and doing the rebase above.

---

Answer (score 6):

### Terminology

First, let's get some terminology out of the way...

**upstream** <= The remote git repo (likely whose master or release branch is in production)

**forked-repo** <= The remote [experimental git repo] (https://docs.github.com/en/github/getting-started-with-github/fork-a-repo) also known as "origin".

**local repo** <= The files and directories that you work with on your local workstaion, which you likely got by running a `git clone my-forked-repo.git` command

**local index** <= Also known as your local git "stage", i.e., where you stage your files before pushing them to you remote repo.

### Github workflow process

Next, let's talk about the process of getting your changes to the upstream repo:

The process is generally to work on a feature branch and then push said branch, and open a Pull Request, either to your forked-repo's **master** branch or to the upstream's **master** branch

Create a feature branch by running `git checkout -b FEATURE_BRANCH_NAME`

Add/delete/modify files project files.

Add files by running `git add .`

Commit your files to your index by running `git commit -m'My commit message'`

Push your staged files by running `git push origin FEATURE_BRANCH_NAME`

### Solution for entirely different commit histories

The **master and upstreambranch are entirely different commit histories** message can occur when you've forked a git repository and have changed your git history.

For example, if you fork a repo and pull your forked repo to work on it locally...

If then you decide to rewrite the entire application and then decide it's a good idea to deleting all existing files, including the forked-repo's .git directory. You add new files and directories to recreate your app and also recreate your .git directory with `git init` command.

Now, your application works great with your new files and you want to get it merged into the upstream repo. However, when you push your changes you get that "...entirely different commit histories..." error message.

You'll see that your original git commit will be different in your new local directory and if in your remote fork (as well as your upstream). Check this out by running this command in your current directory: `git log --reverse master`.  Then running the following: `pushd $(mktemp -d); git clone https://github.com/my-forking-username/my-forked-repo.git; git log --reverse master; popd`

You must fix your local .git repo to match your remote my-forked-repo if you want to push your commits and subsequently perform a pull request (in hopes of merging your new updates to the upstream/master branch).

```
git clone https://github.com/my-forking-username/my-forked-repo.git
cd my-forked-repo
git checkout -b my-new-files-branch-name
# Delete all files and directories except for the .git directory
git add .
git commit -m'Remove old files'
# Copy your new files to this my-forked-repo directory
git add .
git commit -m'Add new files'
git push origin my-new-files-branch-name
```

Create a PR on GitHub and request to merge your my-new-files-branch-name branch in your my-forked-repo into master.

Note: The "...entirely different commit histories..." error message can also occur in non-forked repos for the same reasons and can be fixed with the same solution above.

Answer (score 6):

I got this error when initializing a GitHub repository with a README file, and then trying to push my existing local git repository to it. This resulted in a `main` branch with the README file, which was the Default branch, and a `master` branch with my code, and they couldn't be merged.

But since I didn't actually have anything important in my `main` branch (if you need to keep the data from both your branches, check out PaianuVlad23's Answer instead), I managed to solve the problem by changing the Default branch to the `master` branch, and then delete the `main` branch, like this:

1. When in GitHub, click your user icon in the top right of the window.
2. Choose "Your repositories", and then click your repository name.
3. Under the repository name, choose the tab "Settings".
4. From the pane on the left, choose "Branches".
5. Under the headline "Default", change the default branch from the one you want to delete (in my case `main`) to the one you want to keep (in my case `master`).
6. Now, click the tab "Code" under the repo name.
7. Under the tab line containing "Code" etc, you'll see a place where it says "2 branches". Click it.
8. Find the branch you want to delete, and click the trash bin icon on the right on that line.

Now, your repository has only one branch, which is the one you want to push your local changes to!  Just as if you hadn't initiated your repository before pushing to it, as @mfaani's answer in this thread suggests you do it.

Comment: Very simple solution if you are sure to delete the unwanted branch. It's important to switch the "Default" to the branch you want to keep. Worked perfectly

Answer (score 4):

This happened for me because I created a repo from GH, but then I also added a README. In doing so I created a commit on my remote.

Then I went and created a new repo locally, made some changes and committed. Then I pushed it to the repo and tried to make a Pull Request.

But my remote's initial commit was different from my local's commit, hence this error message. GitHub itself even warns you against this:

> Create a new repository on GitHub.com. **To avoid errors, do not initialize the new repository with README, license, or gitignore files. You can add these files after your project has been pushed to GitHub.**
>
> [GitHub Docs](https://docs.github.com/en/github/importing-your-projects-to-github/importing-source-code-to-github/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line)

Similarly if you're creating a new repo, GitHub will quietly suggest that you skip *initializing* the repo. Rather just *define* the repo.

[image]

tldr the very first commit has to be identical, you can't merge 2 commits that don't have an identical initial commit.

Comment: Great explanation... But what's the solution?

Comment: @KarolinaHagegård just start over the git init. Or like clone the repo on Github into your computer. Then copy/paste all the files into your (other) local repo. merge it. and then push your local repo onto GitHub as a brand new repo. tldr you can't make a **first** commit from **both** GitHub and local repo. creating a README (or any other file) counts as a first commit...

Comment: Thanks. I already solved my issue in the way I explained in an Answer in this thread, but I think your solutions might be a good alternative! However, please edit your Answer to include your solutions step by step with more detail, rather than leaving them as a comment like this... Comments can be cleared away at any time, and shouldn't be considered part of the Answer.  So they say.

Answer (score 3):

A more simple approach where you can't mingle with the master.

Consider i have `master` and `JIRA-1234` branch and when i am trying to merge `JIRA-1234` to `master` i am getting the above issue so please follow below steps:-

1. From `JIRA-1234` cut a branch `JIRA-1234-rebase` (Its a temp branch and can have any name. I have taken `JIRA-1234-rebase` to be meaningful.)

   `git checkout JIRA-1234`

   `git checkout -b JIRA-1234-rebase`
2. The above command will create a new branch `JIRA-1234-rebase` and will checkout it.
3. Now we will rebase our `master`.

   `git rebase master` (This is executed in the same branch `JIRA-1234-rebase`)
4. You will see a window showing the commit history from first commit till the last commit on `JIRA-1234-rebase`. So if we have 98 commits then it will rebase them 1 by 1 and you will see something like 1/98.
5. Here we just need to pick the commit we want so if you want this commit then don't do anything and just HIT `Esc` then `:q!` and HIT `ENTER`.
6. There would be some changes in case of conflict and you need to resolve this conflict and then add the files by

   `git add <FILE_NAME>`.
7. Now do `git rebase continue` it will take you to rebase 2/98 and similarly you have to go through all the 98 commits and resolve all of them and remeber we need to add the files in each commit.
8. Finally you can now push these commits and then raise Pull Request by

   `git push` or `git push origin JIRA-1234-rebase`

Answer (score 2):

If you know from which commit issue started, you can reset your branch to that commit and then merge them.

Answer (score 2):

this is 100% works in any situation :

```
1)create new folder in your machine
2)clone the remote repository to the new folder
3)delete all files and folders except for the .git folder
4)add your project files that you are working on to this new folder you created
5)open terminal
6)cd new_folder_path (path to the new folder you created)
warning : don't type > git init
7) > git add .
8) > git commit -m "write anything"
9) > git push URL(url of the remote repository)local_branch_name:remote_branch_name
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to answer the question unfortunately. You might try to explain a little more about what your process is trying to accomplish.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 1):

This happened with me yesterday cause I downloaded the code from original repo and try to pushed it on my forked repo, spend so much time on searching for solving "Unable to push error" and pushed it forcefully.

Solution:

Simply Refork the repo by deleting previous one and clone the repo from forked repo to the new folder.

Replace the file with old one in new folder and push it to repo and do a new pull request.

Answer (score 1):

I solved that problem. In my case when i did “git clone” in one directory of my choice without do “git init” inside of that repository. Then I moved in to the cloned repository, where already have a “.git” (is a git repository i.e. do not need a “git init”) and finally I started do my changes or anything.

It probably doesn’t solve the problem but shows you how to avoid it.

The command git clone should be a “cd” command imbued if no submodule exists.

Comment: Your answer is not clear, and I fear it doesn't answer the question. I think the expected answer was to push the changes in an upstream branch to be able to compare them.

Answer (score 0):

I found that none of the answers provided actually worked for me; what actually worked for me is to do:

```
git push --set-upstream origin *BRANCHNAME*
```

After creating a new branch, then it gets tracked properly.  (I have Git 2.7.4)

Answer (score 0):

**I don't think we have same case here**, but still **someone else may find it helpful**.

When similar error occurred to me, it was going to be the first merge and first commit. There was nothing in on-line repository.
Therefore, there was no code on git-hub, to compare with.

**I simply deleted the empty repository and created new one with same name.**
And then there was no error.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error message, because I was migrating an application from SVN to GitHub and it's not enough to invoke a *git init* in the location of the source code checked out from SVN, but you need to invoke a *git svn clone*  in order to have all the commit history.
This way the two source codes on GitHub will have a mutual history and I was able to open pull requests.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue where I was pushing to my remote repo from a local repo that didn't match up with history of remote. This is what worked for me.

**I cloned my repo locally so I knew I was working with fresh copy of repo:**

```
git clone Your_REPO_URL_HERE.git
```

**Switch to the branch you are trying to get into the remote:**

```
git checkout Your_BRANCH_NAME_HERE
```

**Add the remote of the original:**

```
git remote add upstream Your_REMOTE_REPO_URL_HERE.git
```

**Do a git fetch and git pull:**

```
git fetch --all

git pull upstream Your_BRANCH_NAME_HERE
```

**If you have merge conflicts, resolve them with**

```
git mergetool kdiff3
```

or other merge tool of your choice.

Once conflicts are resolved and saved. Commit and push changes.

Now go to the gitub.com repo of the original and attempt to create a pull request. You should have option to create pull request and not see the "Nothing to compare, branches are entirely different commit histories"
Note: You may need to choose compare across forks for your pull request.

Answer (score 0):

Top guy is probably right that you downloaded instead of cloning the repo at start. 
Here is a easy solution without getting too technical.

- In a new editor window, clone your repo in another directory.
- Make a new branch.
- Then copy from your your edited editor window into your new repo by copy paste.

Make sure that all your edits are copied over by looking at your older github branch.

Answer (score 0):

I had mine solved by overriding the branch:

My case: I wanted to override whatever code is in the `develop` with `version_2`.

1. delete the local copy of conflicting branch:

```
git checkout version_2
git branch -D develop
```

2. checkout a fresh branch from the `version_2` and force push to git:

```
git checkout -b `develop`
git push origin `develop`
```

I didn't need to rebase. But in my case, I didn't need to take code from my old code.

Answer (score 0):

1. first: pull from remote repo
2. merge or rebase
3. finally: push to remote repo
4. finish

Answer (score 0):

When you are pull/merging feature to main and are in the main branch in the terminal, I successfully used 'git pull origin feature --allow-unrelated-histories'.
Before using this command, I had the same message about completely different commit histories, and I think it's because I accidentally pushed to main after committing to the feature branch. Then I tried some of the solutions offered here like rebase, which allowed me to merge my code, but I still had the compare and pull notifications through git, and it was a one time fix. By one time fix I mean I still got the different commit history message the next time I tried to merge a feature branch's code to main.
Another source from a google search offered the --allow-unrelated-histories fix, and it permanently works exactly how I wanted it to. The branches were merged and now I can merge without error messages and the compare and pull notifications work through git.
I'm sure there are consequences for people who didn't have the same problem as me, but I didn't lose any code and now my repo is clean. Also, I'm also an amateur coder and the question is older so maybe this command wasn't available when the question was asked or I'm not understanding the issue correctly.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [answer].

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered the same issues and this is how I fix

```
git checkout master
git pull origin/master
```

Then I created the backup

```
git checkout -b backup-master
```

Then I just pull the **unrelated branch** from origin and merge

```
git checkout master
git merge -X theirs origin/unrelated-branch --allow-unrelated-histories
```

**LONG ANSWER**

This command does two things

1. Merge the master with the lasted code of an Unrelated branch - {unrelated-branch} `-X theirs` option ensures that the remote files overwrite the local files. Got the concept from [SO here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40517129/git-merge-with-force-overwrite)
2. Force Git to merge the unrelated branches

[[image: Entering the command in Bash file1]

Answer (score 0):

What I did is -

1. I created another branch from the updated branch
2. then I removed everything from that branch
3. and finally pasted updated things on it

I lost my github history, but worked since I was in a hurry.

Answer (score -1):

I wanted to copy commit history of "master" branch & overwrite the commit history of "main" branch .
The steps are:-

1. git checkout master
2. git branch main master -f
3. git checkout main
4. git push

To **delete master branch**:-

**a. Locally**:-

5. git checkout main
6. git branch -d master

**b. Globally:-**

7. git push origin --delete master