# How to do a pull request when my branch and master have no related history?

Tags: git, github

I have a branch, "branch_x", that is part of the same repository as master. However, I foolishly started developing on branch_x without checking out from master. Therefore there is no common ancestor between master and branch_x, and when I tried doing a pull request to master, I simply got: **There isn’t anything to compare.
master and branch_x are entirely different commit histories.**

Because of that fault, I made a fork of that repository. I am trying to merge the commits of branch_x into the master branch of the fork, and then I will try to request a pull between original repository and the fork (because now they have some history in common). However, I have no idea of how to actually merge branch_x from the original repo, to the master branch of the fork.

This post is similar, but I don't think that "git rebase -onto" will help much: [There isn't anything to compare. Nothing to compare, branches are entirely different commit histories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23344320/there-isnt-anything-to-compare-nothing-to-compare-branches-are-entirely-diffe)

Comment: You could try creating a branch from `master` named `branch_x2`, and then manually bringing your changes from `branch_x` into your new `branch_x2`. You would then have a branch with a common ancestor of `master` that you could try merging back in.

Comment: Would I have to delete the fork? Because I thought I could do all of that with the fork, excluding the new branch ("branch_x2").

Comment: You should create the new `branch_x2` on your fork, replicate your `branch_x` changes in `branch_x2`, and then make a pull request from `yourfork:branch_x2` to `upstream:master`. So yes, you should be able to do all of this within your fork.

Comment: Thanks, that does make sense. However, I don't know how to replicate branch_x changes in branch_x2. Is this using merge? I am still new to Git

Comment: No worries! First, make sure you've got `branch_x2` checked out: `git checkout -b branch_x2`. Then, copy the files from `branch_x` using regular Windows copy commands and paste/overwrite the files in your fork where you have `branch_x2` checked out. Running `git status` should then show you all of your changes from `branch_x`, but now in `branch_x2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As seen in @Adil B comment, the answer to this solution was to make the new branch_x2, within the fork. Then, copy and replace the files representing the most recent commit in branch_x of the original repo, to branch_x2. You will now have a related history, and the files you want to compare. You can be on either branch (when in the fork) and do the pull request, as long as that branch represents the commit and files/directories that you need.

Comment: This is kind of a manual work around that allows you to have a related history.  while it does solve the problem, it doesn't really answer your original question.

Answer (score 19):

I found this to work, the --allow-unrelated-histories flag

```
git add .
git commit -m "message"
git pull origin main(or whatever branch) --allow-unrelated-histories
git push origin branch_x
```

you should now be able to compare and PR

Answer (score 13):

This is easily doable by doing the following:

1. Checkout `branch_x` to work on it:

   `git checkout branch_x`
2. Reset soft to `master` so that `branch_x` is now at the same place than `master` in the git history but all your changes are now staged (`reset --soft` doesn't touch files in the working directory and even add the changes directly to the staging area):

   `git reset --soft master`
3. Commit the files so that it will create one commit containing just the changes made in `branch_x` compared to `master`

   `git commit`

And now `branch_x` is one commit ahead of `master` and you can create your PR. You perhaps will have to `push --force` depending if you already pushed `branch_x`

Comment: Old commits on the checked-out branch (not the reset one) seem to have become disassociated with the branch, though their contents remained.  I found this result strange, but I was able to complete the PR successfully.

Comment: if you're resorting to `--force` you're doing it wrong. that is most likely not needed for these purposes unless you're trying to augment git history.  this answer will most likely work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63603128/349100

Comment: @Sonic-soul the 2 solutions don't express the same thing and as the original question was more about fixing an error, my solution is better because you end up in the exact same state than if you didn't do the error. And doing a '--force' to have a better history sometimes outweigh the disadvantages. And your 'augment git history' means nothing.