# There isn’t anything to compare

Tags: git, github, terminal

master and ishfaq_web_event_tracking_changes are entirely different commit histories

```
git init
git remote add origin <url>
git checkout <branch>
git add .
git commit -m"new changes to branch"
git pull
git push origin <branch>
```

changes are committing success, but I am unable to create a new pull request

please visit screen short,

[image]

Comment: this link may help you. I think it's the same problem, occurring when you checkout to branch. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23344320/there-isnt-anything-to-compare-nothing-to-compare-branches-are-entirely-diffe

Comment: tried but no luck

Comment: Try restarting from the top, but skipping `git checkout <branch>`.  Also, replace `git push origin <branch>` to `git push origin master`.