# GitHub/Git: Can't create pull request (no button) with specific branch

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I have 3 branch: `main`, `test-1.1` and `myName`.
If I try to create pull request with `myName` and `main`, I will be able to do it:
[image]

But know, if I replace `main` with my `test-1.1` branch, it gives me that:
[image]
But, why ? I want to merge with `test-1.1` but I am not able to.
How to resolve this ?

Comment: Typical case of unrelated histories, as already pointed out by others. A rebase is what you would might need. [This other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23344320/there-isnt-anything-to-compare-nothing-to-compare-branches-are-entirely-diffe) might help you.

Comment: This one seems to have a clearer set of answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40107973/736079

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have two branches that (no longer) share the same root-commit. Therefore, GitHub can't generate a Pull Request for you. Technically your two branches are totally unrelated (even if they contain similar content).

Comment: so, how can I resolve it ?

Comment: from branch `myName` run `git pull origin test-1.1 --allow-unrelated-histories` or vice versa. https://reactgo.com/git-merge-unrelated-histories/ This will merge these branches back together locally. It looks like you'll then have to force-push. Make sure you havn backups. There be dragons.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40107973/736079

Comment: i had two branches unrelated branches with main and master, this is how it worked for me                                                                                                                         
 `git checkout master
git branch main master -f    
git checkout main
git push origin main -f `

Answer (score 0):

Do `main`, `test-1.1`, and `myName` all belong to the same branch?

To answer for your specific case, we'd need more information (what was on the branches) because [github](https://docs.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-pull-requests/proposing-changes-to-your-work-with-pull-requests/about-pull-requests) is comparing branches and telling you which ones can be merged and which cannot. If they can be merged, github is allowing you to create a pull request to merge `myName` into `master`. There must be 'merge conflicts' between the `myName` and `test-1.1` branch.

Comment: Yes, same repository...