# Can't make a pull request

Tags: node.js, reactjs, git, github

I have this repository that i forked from another one, and now i need to make a pull request to it, but it says that: "There isn’t anything to compare.", and my commits are not showing:
https://github.com/amorimll/desafio-sharenergy-2023-01
[image]

Any help is appreciated, really need this for today.

This is showing in the git rebase:

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23344320/there-isnt-anything-to-compare-nothing-to-compare-branches-are-entirely-diffe

Comment: this seems like the solution you need to me

Comment: is your main branch have any commits ahead your current master branch? if  so you need to do rebase or merge first then to create a PR

Comment: So I saw the link you posted. it said `This branch is 16 commits ahead, 1 commit behind SHARENERGY-OFICIAL:main.` and you need to fixed this 1 commit behind by rebase as i mentioned above, then you should be good to go

Comment: Ok, i'm doing it

Comment: what you typed for command?

Comment: I didn't type, i just used the rebase command and this appeared

Comment: did you clean the current branch your working on? you need to save all the changes first. it said `please enter the commit message for your changes`

Answer (score 1):

### Short answer

will be checkout to your `main` branch get the lastest code, then go back to your current working on branch and do `git rebase [currentBranchName] main`

### Explain

so when your create a branch from another branch, is like your created a snapshot code from that branch at that moment. ideally the branch you copied form should prevent make any more changes if possible, until you done working in the new branch and create the `PR` and done marge it.
what `rebase` command will do is in case the origin branch had changes, it will pull the latest code form that branch into your working branch first, then to applied any changes you was made for your current working branch. Usually this process will need have some conflict need to fix, if they changed the same file.

Hope this is help you understand :)