# I accidentally run `git branch <branchA> <branchB> -f` and can't go back to previous state

Tags: git, github

I accidentally run `git branch <branchA> <branchB> -f` and can't go back to previous state...
As a result of that, I received too many changes...

I originally wrote the architecture using Draw.io in a branch I created a long time ago. When I thought it was time to merge it, I couldn't do it because I got the following message.

`There isn't anything to compare. master and document/initial-architecture are entirely different commit histories.`

[image]

So I looked at this URL ([There isn't anything to compare. Nothing to compare, branches are entirely different commit histories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23344320/there-isnt-anything-to-compare-nothing-to-compare-branches-are-entirely-diffe)).

So I ran the following code.

```
81906@DESKTOP-608QNA0 MINGW64 ~/Documents/slackbot-gpt3 (document/initial-architecture)
$ git branch master document/initial-architecture -f

81906@DESKTOP-608QNA0 MINGW64 ~/Documents/slackbot-gpt3 (document/initial-architecture)
$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master
Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
and have 25 and 28 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)

81906@DESKTOP-608QNA0 MINGW64 ~/Documents/slackbot-gpt3 (master)
$ git push origin master -f
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: error: GH006: Protected branch update failed for refs/heads/master.
remote: error: Cannot force-push to this protected branch
To https://github.com/Suchica/slackgpt3.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (protected branch hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/Suchica/slackgpt3.git'.
```

Here, 37 changes have occurred, and I want to undo them, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to do it. The Git graph looks like this.

[image]

And here is the result of `git reflog`.

[image]

Comment: Added the result of `git reflog`

Answer (score 1):

`git reflog` might save you if you haven't made too many moves since.

`git reflog` shows your movements rather than your branches history, find the SHA of the last good place and `git reset --hard _YOUR_SHA_`.

YMMV.

Comment: I pasted the results of the git reflog. What SHA number should I go back to before running `git branch master document/initial-architecture -f` ?

Comment: my gut says `git reset --hard 7ede281` is what you want BUT from my seat it's very hard to say for certain. I say `7ede281` because this LOOKS LIKE the most recent bit of actual commited work (`Improved the beginning of the prompt...`). Again, YMMV, proceed with caution, and godspeed.

Comment: I would suggest reading the docs for `reflog` but git docs are notoriously dense :o

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog

Comment: You can think of traversing the reflog as travelling back in time. In theory if you don't go passed any `commit` entries you shouldn't lose anything good, you should land back where you were when you made that commit, and you get a do-over on your rebase or whatever else you did after.

Comment: if you change your mind after you`git reset --hard 7ede281` you can always `git reset --hard a6d71e5` to go back... to the future!

Answer (score 1):

```
git branch -f branchA branchA@{1}
```

See [the reflog syntax in `git help revisions`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#Documentation/gitrevisions.txt-emltrefnamegtltngtemegemmaster1em).

The @{1} syntax is the pretty-much-universal backout from oopses like this.

Shell history expansion (introduced by `!`) has a "current line" marker `#`, and a "last word" selector `$`, making the totally-unnecessary-here shorthand for repeating the branch name

```
git branch -f branchA !#$@{1}
```

which I like too much to not mention.

Comment: I pasted the results of the git reflog. What SHA number should I go back to before running `git branch master document/initial-architecture -f` ?