# How to pull somebody else's commits I just rewrited by push --force

Tags: git, github, git-remote

This is what I have done:

```
git commit -m 'feature 1 implemented'
git push origin feature-branch
```

..few days later

```
git commit --amend --no-edit 
git push -f origin feature-branch
```

And then I realised that feature branch have contained commits pushed by others which I just screw up because I forgot to 
`git pull`

As I understood from another questions git push --force can be easily undone

- if you have working local copy
- if you can get the commit sha

But in my case I don't know these details, I have rewritten others commits

I know I can ask my teammembers to force update without pulling, but still

Is there a way to undo --force push 
and git pull this data ?

Comment: Usage of push with forse option is not good idea in case if branch is using by more then one developer.

Answer (score 0):

just found the solution here [How to recover from a git push -force?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12568628/how-to-recover-from-a-git-push-force)

All I needed was

```
git reset --hard origin/feature-branch@{1}
```

(I could see the missing commints in git status)

```
git push -f origin feature-branch
```