# All existing folders and files in git repository master branch got replaced with new files

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

```
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in C:/Users/myname/IdeaProjects/ProjectName/.git
$ git remote add origin https://myname@bitbucket.org/abc/xyz-repository.git
$ git status
On branch master
No commits yet
Untracked files:
(use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
.gitignore
.idea/
ProjectName.iml
generated-sources/
pom.xml
src/
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
$ git add . 

FEW WARNINGS...

$git commit -am "New Project"

$ git push -f origin master
```

Now every folder and file in the xyz-repository.git is replaced with the new files making a new master branch overriding the existing once, ALL commit ids are gone.

How can I revert all I have done? I want to go back to the previous master branch which has folders and files.

Comment: This is why you should never force-push to `master`, or let people do so...

Comment: seems like a dupe of [How to recover from a git push -force?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12568628/how-to-recover-from-a-git-push-force)

Comment: @underscore_d how is this different from **How to recover from a git push -force?** All the existing commits were lost and replaced with the new commit id.

Comment: That's still a force push. It doesn't matter how much of the history was rewritten: it _was_. Recovery follows the same principles either way.

Comment: @underscore_d really thank you:) it worked now after a little bit of depth understanding. Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad to hear it! :-D