# Git - couldn't pull, tried to force, now not sure where I am

Tags: git, github, merge, push, branch

I'll try to explain what I did.

My last commit and push to github was at least a couple weeks ago.

I've still been committing regularly.

Recently, I tried to merge changes, but I wasn't able to because I had changed the readme manually on github and needed to pull it down first.

I tried to pull, but that opened VIM.

I tried to enter a commit message like it was asking but I'm not familiar with VIM and I'm not sure if I was successful or not.

I followed some instructions, but I can't remember exactly what happened. I don't think it was successful because the next thing I decided to do was just force a push.

I had everything I wanted locally, expect for the readme, so I figured it wouldn't be that big a deal.

But after doing that, I decided I should try to go back and save the readme first, duh!

I looked up how to go back to the previous commit and followed the first answer here:

[How to recover from a git push -force?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12568628/how-to-recover-from-a-git-push-force)

basically this

```
# work on local master
git checkout master

# reset to the previous state of origin/master, as recorded by reflog
git reset --hard origin/master@{1}

# at this point verify that this is indeed the desired commit.
# (if necessary, use git reflog to find the right one, and
# git reset --hard to that one)

# finally, push the master branch (and only the master branch) to the server
git push -f origin master
```

Now it looks like instead of being at my previous local commit, I'm at the last commit I pushed to GitHub a couple weeks ago. Is that possible?

Can anyone straighten me out with this?
At this point, I'd just like to get back to my previous local commit.

If I loose the readme no big deal.

Here's my git reflog - I'd like to go back to 'fixed a typo'

[image]

Comment: `git reflog`  See where you where, and reset to it.

Comment: thanks, I added a screenshot of my reflog. I'd like to go back to 'fixed a typo'. I'm looking online, but if you'd like to answer I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your reflog, it looks like you just want to do:

```
git reset 27f3f76
```

Assuming you don't mind modifying your working directory, you probably want:

```
git reset --hard 27f3f76  # Caution: will modify working directory
```

Comment: thanks, so I think I want --hard, but I'm not sure what the difference is.

Comment: also, from the reflog, it looks like my pull was successful. Shouldn't that have given me what I wanted with the correct readme?