# Git rebase and merge

Tags: git, merge, rebase

> My remote master branch: `A D`
>
> My remote dev branch: `A B`
>
> My local dev branch: `A B C`
>
> Current Merge request in Github: `remote dev -> remote master`
>
> How can I make the remote dev branch as `A D B' C'`, so that I can
> make the remote master branch as `A D B' C'` by just approving current
> Merge request?

What I did is

> 1. making the local dev branch `A D B' C'`
> 2. tried to push local dev branch which is now `A D B' C'` to the remote dev branch which is `A B`

and as you can guess, it said

> "Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is
> behind"

Could you let me know what is the best practice here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind its remote counterpart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39399804/updates-were-rejected-because-the-tip-of-your-current-branch-is-behind-its-remot) - all that’s required is to force-push

Answer (score 0):

## TL;DR

After you did make the local dev branch to match `A D B C`, all you need to do is a force push instead of just a normal push:

```
git push -f
```

---

## Comprehensive answer

(including to make the local dev branch match `A D B C`)

Your scenario sounds really strange, because you have a commit (`D`) on master, but not on develop. However, it should be possible to achieve what you want (getting `A D B' C'` in dev branch).

First the key tools, which should help achieving the desired goal (I find the linked tutorials quite nice to read, so that should explain the commands well):

- [git cherry-pick](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/cherry-pick)
- [git rebase](https://www.atlassian.com/de/git/tutorials/rewriting-history/git-rebase)

Now, I try to explain step by step how it should work. I have not tried it myself since it's a bit of a special setup. I will perform all operations on local develop branch with a final force push to overwrite the history and remote branch. Also I'll provide an expected output after each step.

Cherry pick the commit you like to have on develop branch:

```
git cherry-pick D
```

Now, your develop branch should look like this: `A B C D`.

In the next step you will re-arrange the order of the commits using rebase:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~4
```

You should get following editor view:

```
pick A
pick B
pick C
pick D

# Rebase ...
#
# Commands:
#  p, pick = use commit
#  e, edit = use commit, but stop for amending
#  s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
#
# If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST.
# However, if you remove everything, the rebase will be aborted.
#
```

In order to change the commit order just cut the line of commit `D` and paste it after `A` (then save and close the editor):

```
pick A
pick D
pick B
pick C

# Rebase ...
#
# Commands:
#  p, pick = use commit
#  e, edit = use commit, but stop for amending
#  s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
#
# If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST.
# However, if you remove everything, the rebase will be aborted.
#
```

I hope you don't get conflicts, but if you do you have to solve them (I'll skip on this).

Eventually, your local develop branch should look like the desired output: `A D B C`. Therefore, you can now force push (DISCLAIMER: only force push if the local branch is correct! It will overwrite your remote branch and it's not as simple to recover it; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12569664/6180150)):

```
git push -f
```

This will update the remote develop branch to the desired output: `A D B C`.

I hope everything works as expected and it's somehow understandable how I explained it.

Comment: I think it is not that strange. I started from the master when it does not have a commit D yet, and while I am working on dev branch by committing B, C, another team mate made a update in the remote master branch by committing D. (which is really common)

Comment: Ok. I see. Did my advice help? Could you solve it with a force push?

Comment: @AD7six How would you undo a force push? I would really like to know how if I’m mistaken and it’s possible.

Comment: @AD7six thanks. I wasn't aware of that, but still I would categorize it as more advanced git knowledge. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Yea I know, but I guess it may help someone else who does not know how to achieve this step from question: "making the local dev branch A D B' C'". I'll also add a TL;DR section for the force push. I'm also fine with the down vote if you still find the answer too long. Trying to improve it :)

Comment: It’s always better to (just) answer the asked question, that’ll do for now though :)