# Git undo push -f on all branches

Tags: git, github, push

I am in deep s***; I coded a small fix on a branch on which I was working. For some reason, it didn't want to push because it was "behind his remote counterpart" which is impossible because I am the only one working on that branch. My collegue told me to do a push -f which I did. But it pushed all my local branches to remote and replaced everything with the versions I had on my local repo; the last commit on master is now 22 days ago. We lost an enormous amount of work. How to rollback the git push -f on all branches ?

Comment: well part of the problem is answered in the other answer, that's why I linked it. However, the solution I posted is more specific to this problem (pushed ALL branches with -f)

Comment: IMO there's little point in littering SO with threads which bear 99% similarity, so new questions which arise due to not properly searching the existing base first should be closed. Also I'd say to force-push *all* branches is a dangerous over-simplification: a person who did a slip like yours should carefully examine the situation and think a recovery plan. If in your *particular* case all branches were reset it *might have been* okay to force-push all the branches, but it's not necessarily so in a different situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it arranged somehow.

[Is there anyway to undo git push -f?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14476236/is-there-anyway-to-undo-git-push-f) helped me a lot

What I did is using the commit refs showing during the push -f which look like

```
e658r75...63ehd63 master -> master (forced update)
e23r433...29e23gz dev -> dev(forced update)
```

I have set my config default to push **only current branch** before doing anything

```
git config --global push.default current
```

Then, for **each one** of the branches that I had overwritten,  I **used the ref shown the push -f** before the "..." and did :

```
git checkout master
git push -f origin e658r75:master
git pull origin master
```

**That sets the branch on remote and local repos at the point it was before the push -f.**

Note that after the push to ref:branch, my local branches were not at their HEAD state(which was still the old local version), that's why I had to pull the remote ones to reset them.

Answer (score 1):

The last committer (for each branch) needs to push his last commits. And use always:

`git push -f <remote> <branch>`

if you want to force a push.

Comment: of course if the last committer of each branch pushes its local version it works, but when you got a lot of people working on a lot of branches this is not as simple as that :) . By the way I agree git push -f <remote> <branch>, now I changed the default config to avoid this kind of problems

Comment: The other solution is to delete the commit you have committed. When somebody will commit the delete changes will re-pushed to the server. Ask to each to make `git push` to get a stable repo now.

Comment: Another hint, forbid forced push on the shared branches (master, next, v???...). Make a forced on these branches is only painful.