# Git undo a change in a folder that was a part of .gitignore

Tags: node.js, git, npm

I am building a theme for NodeBB and the theme lives inside the `node_modules` directory. Pulling in from master last night I have a new `.gitignore` my file had ignore all `node_modules` except for my theme, well since this is a new `.gitignore` it didn't track my changes.

Then I made changes to my theme without it being tracked. I decided to merge with  my repo, after some conflicts took a step back then did `npm prune` now this pruned my theme, I spent the last hour making changes that I am not sure I can get back.

My question is since the folder was not being tracked is it possible to undo the `npm prune` and recover the theme within `node_modules`?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think so. If git was not tracking the files at all, you can't get them back (unless you used to have them in the repo, but still, the latest changes that you lost would not be part of it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, I think you won't be able to get your files back.

If you added the files or the directories to .gitignore, then git wasn't tracking them. So you cannot get them back with git, unless you used to have them in the repo, but even if you did, the latest changes that you lost would not be part of the repo. Sorry for the negative answer.

However, all is probably not lost right now. If you immediately unmounted the file system or remounted it read-only as soon as you realised you deleted your theme, you could always try a file recovery tool such as `photorec`.

Comment: Cool man, this is good to know. Thankfully they were minor CSS changes and I was able to remember most changes I made, but it's still definitely a pain having to repeat the exact changes you made 1 hour ago lol. At least it was much faster the second time around.

Comment: Glad to hear you didn't lose your changes completely. I once did a similar mistake, `git clean`ing files. And of course, the files I mistakenly deleted were not (yet) tracked by git.

Comment: Well afterwards I found I did a force push and lost a plugin I was working on, but thankfully I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3973994/how-can-i-recover-from-an-erronous-git-push-f-origin-master `git reflog show remotes/origin/master` let me get the plugin back :) All is well now, I hoped for a productive day but unfortunately 5 hours later and I am pretty much where I started last night lol.