# Can I undo reseted commits in a GitHub repo?

Tags: git

Due to some bugs I couldn't solve, I've cloned my last GitHub repo commit.
The app started working again. Then I pushed it back to the same repo, but the commits number got reseted to 1. Any way I can undo this?

Comment: Did you `git push --force`...?

Comment: Perhaps post a link to your repo or add more details

Comment: Also, check `git reflog` and `git fsck --unreachable`

Comment: @Mateen Yes, I had to use git push --force.

Comment: 1. Backup your `.git` folder. 2. Do the other two things I said. 3. "Don't use the `--force` Luke!" is valid advice for the future until you're 100% comfortable with git and know when it's OK to use.

Comment: I know "--force" seemed just wrong, but that was the only way to push my changes since it wouldn't stop returning errors after errors. Thanks for the advice, though. So how do I back my git folder up? Been searching for a while and still have no clue...

Comment: It's inside your project. `ls -a`. So something like `tar cf git_backup.tar .git`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To go back to the state before your git push --force, check the output of [`git reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog)

Or look at the events in your [GitHub repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48110879/6309)

The idea is to reset locally to what you had before, then force push again, in order to reset the remote repository to its previous state.

Then you can clone again, make your fixes, add, commmit and do a regular push.