# How to get readme.md file that exists on a remote branch that I force pushed

Tags: git, github, readme

This is my problem:

I wrote a long `readme.md` file in github(for the first time in my life) and, as always, force pushed. So the file disappeared and I don't have it on my local machine. I searched for instructions on how to get back that file but didn't found any.

So is there a way to somehow get that file back?

Would be grateful for any help. Thanks :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I recover from an erronous git push -f origin master?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3973994/how-can-i-recover-from-an-erronous-git-push-f-origin-master)

Comment: I tried those solutions. For me, they don't give errors, but still don't work. Any other answers. Or if they definitely must help, could you please write it step by step. Maybe I miss something. Thanks.