# How to recover readme file from github?

Tags: github

I have a github repository and I created a Readme file and wrote inside. Atfet that I worked and writed code in VS code and pushed the code to the github. In that moment my Readme file I created before was deleted.

I used tu push:

```
git add -u
git push -f
```

Can I recover that README file?

Comment: if the file exists in the githublog you can create another clone and revert this to the revisoin with the readme file, and add into the "original" clone then commit and push with restored file

Comment: This could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3973994/how-can-i-recover-from-an-erronous-git-push-f-origin-master