# How to fix overriding the main branch in Git?

Tags: git, reset, rebase, git-revert

I override the main branch by:

`git rebase feature/create_ffmpeg_dockerfil`

`git push origin feature/create_ffmpeg_dockerfile`

`git push -f -u origin feature/create_ffmpeg_dockerfile`

`git checkout feature/create_ffmpeg_dockerfile` 
`git branch main feature/create_ffmpeg_dockerfile -f` 
`git checkout main`
`git push origin main -f`

my commite appear in the main branch
how can I restore the main?

I try this:
`git rebase --abort`
fatal: No rebase in progress

and also this:
`git revert <commit id>`
error: Reverting is not possible because you have unmerged files.
hint: Fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm '
hint: as appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit.
fatal: revert failed

Comment: What do you mean by "fix overriding"? Undo `git push -f`?

Comment: This is extremely unclear. IF your local `feature/create_ffmpeg_dockerfile` branch was (probably by mistake) set to track and push to `origin/main` (still possible) **before** the first push command, yes it might have pushed commits to it, but *not* "override" (although we have to wildly guess what you meant by this non-git term). Then the second push will have repaired the wrongly assigned remote branch and pushed to `origin/feature/create_ffmpeg_dockerfile`. Then you might want to undo the push to `main`? All this is speculation. Please clarify.

Comment: What I guess is that you have force pushed and now you want to revert it. If this is the case please check link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3973994/how-can-i-recover-from-an-erronous-git-push-f-origin-master and let me know if this proves to be helpful. Apart from it you are not trying correct commands. As error message indicates git rebase --abort is used when you have rebase in progress. You have no rebase in progress so no use of running it.  Check https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase to know what is git rebase. For second command error message may indicate you have unstaged files.